# How do I integrate wit.ai and hubot?

Tags: wit.ai, hubot, discourse

I want to integrate wit.ai with hubot.  Besides that I have hubot running on a discourse forum server via an adapter.  That is secondary.

I installed https://github.com/guillaumewuip/hubot-wit-helper, installed the npm package, but I get this error when I run bin/hubot

```
[wit] Stories and POST /converse have been deprecated. This will break in February 2018!
[Thu Mar 01 2018 01:44:58 GMT+0000 (UTC)] ERROR Unable to load /var/discourse/avebot/scripts/avebot: Error: The 'send' action is missing. Learn more at https://wit.ai/docs/quickstart
  at validateActions (/var/discourse/avebot/node_modules/node-wit/lib/wit.js:223:11)
  at validate (/var/discourse/avebot/node_modules/node-wit/lib/wit.js:212:20)
  at new Wit (/var/discourse/avebot/node_modules/node-wit/lib/wit.js:20:35)
  at new Robot (/var/discourse/avebot/node_modules/hubot-wit-helper/lib/Robot.js:24:24)
  at bot (/var/discourse/avebot/scripts/avebot.js:28:26)
  at Robot.loadFile (/var/discourse/avebot/node_modules/hubot/src/robot.coffee:358:11, <js>:226:13)
  at Robot.load (/var/discourse/avebot/node_modules/hubot/src/robot.coffee:377:9, <js>:247:30)
  at Discourse.loadScripts (/var/discourse/avebot/node_modules/hubot/bin/hubot:93:5, <js>:97:13)
  at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:219:13)
  at Discourse.emit (events.js:127:13)
  at Discourse.run (/var/discourse/avebot/node_modules/hubot-discourse-adapter/src/discourse.coffee:63:5, <js>:89:12)
  at Robot.run (/var/discourse/avebot/node_modules/hubot/src/robot.coffee:590:5, <js>:464:27)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/var/discourse/avebot/node_modules/hubot/bin/hubot:168:8, <js>:182:11)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/var/discourse/avebot/node_modules/hubot/bin/hubot:5:1, <js>:185:4)
  at Module._compile (module.js:662:30)
  at Object.exports.run (/var/discourse/avebot/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:103:25)
  at compileScript (/var/discourse/avebot/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:171:29)
  at /var/discourse/avebot/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:143:18
  at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:532:3)
```

I put the server token in the wit_token = 'mywittoken' part of the example script found on the github page above, which starts like this

```
'use strict';

(() => {

    const witHelper = require('hubot-wit-helper');

    const WIT_TOKEN = 'myWitToken';
```

How do I get it all to work?  Is it too old to use?

Answer (score 0):

Wit.ai discontinued stories and /converse as of February 13, 2018 10am PST

The `hubot-wit-helper` npm package appears to still use stories through `wit.runActions()` [hubot-wit-helper/lib/Robot.js line 72] which will no longer work as of the discontinuation of Wit stories.

To get wit.ai working again in this package you need to follow [the official guide](https://github.com/wit-ai/wit-stories-migration-tutorial) on how to migrate the codebase from stories to the /message API.